# How can I perform string manipulations inside an amp-list template?

Tags: amp-html

I can use `amp-bind` to update `[href]` for an anchor. If I include this same anchor in an `amp-list` template, though, `[href]` appears to mangled when the template is applied (it is prepended by the origin location and URI encoded). Notably, single quotes are missing around strings, resulting in an expression compile error.

In the following example, the link before `amp-list` updates fine on the button press, whereas the link produced by the `amp-list` template becomes mangled. Interestingly, the anchor *in* the template still reads fine; it's only after the template is applied that `[href]` gets mangled.

Anchor inside template:

```
<a href="https://amp-test/" [href]="path ? 'https://amp-test/' + path.split(' ').join('-') : 'https://amp-test/'">{{linkName}}</a>
```

Anchor after template is applied:

```
<a href="https://amp-test/" [href]="https://amp-test/path%20?%20%27https://amp-test/%27%20+%20path.split(%27%20%27).join(%27-%27)%20:%20%27https://amp-test/%27" target="_top" class="i-amphtml-error">one path</a>
```

So, some questions that might accompany the title question include: Are `amp-bind` operations supposed to work inside `amp-list`? i.e is what I'm seeing the expected behavior or a bug?

**Minimal Example** ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmeawk6r/3/))

*results.json*

```
{
    "items": [
        { "linkName": "one path" },
        { "linkName": "two path" }
    ]
}
```

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
    <title>amp-bind in amp-list</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://cmphys.com/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

    <style amp-custom>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button on="tap:AMP.setState({path: 'relative path'})">Update</button>

    <hr>
    <p>
        <a href="https://amp-test/" [href]="path ? 'https://amp-test/' + path.split(' ').join('-') : 'https://amp-test/'">link</a>
    </p>

    <hr>
    <amp-list id="myList" class="list" layout="fixed" width="200" height="100" src="/results.json">
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            <a href="https://amp-test/" [href]="path ? 'https://amp-test/' + path.split(' ').join('-') : 'https://amp-test/'">{{linkName}}</a><br>
        </template>
    </amp-list>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Sanitizers](https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/blob/master/readme.md#custom-sanitizer) to manipulate your post's AMP content. For this, you should avoid banned URL protocols or expressions that would fail the AMP Validator.

Regarding amp-bind operations inside amp-list, you may want to check this [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#element-specific-attributes) wherein it's mentioned that binding to `<amp-list>` components and attributes is allowed and it's behavior is that:

> If expression is a string, fetches and renders JSON from the string URL. If expression is an object or array, renders the expression data.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're recommending use of sanitization; I'm starting from an AMP HTML document, not converting a page from HTML to AMP HTML.

The document you pointed to (and quoted) refers only to the amp-list attribute [src], not element attributes within an amp-list template.